# Content Tools add br instead of p when pressing the Enter

Tags: javascript

[Content Tools](http://getcontenttools.com/)

I need to when pressing the "enter" instead tag p add tag br,
how it can be implemented?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ContentEdit (which is part of ContentTools) provides a setting to allow you to configure the behaviour of the return key in `Text` elements - `PREFER_LINE_BREAKS` (see the settings documentation here: http://getcontenttools.com/api/content-edit#settings).

So to configure your application to insert line breaks (`br` tags) when the enter key is pressed you need to set `PREFER_LINE_BREAKS` to `true` like so:

```
ContentEdit.PREFER_LINE_BREAKS = true;
```